# What is the correct way to host 2 SPA on the same domain name?

Tags: angular, devops, web-hosting

I am dealing with an issue. We want multiple SPA (this is an angular website) to be hosted on the same domain name. The apps are called app1 and app2. We have 2 options from what I see to be able to do it. We can host the apps so that they are on different sub domains or be accessed via path parameters. For example: app1.example.com and app2.example.com or example.com/app1 and example.com/app2 ... It doesnt matter which approach we take from a business point of view, we just want to make sure we do it the right way which brings me to my question. What is the right way to host app1 and app2 on example.com? Also these apps will be hosted in kubernetes on separate nginx containers.

Comment: What I could think of is using different port number. What is your requirement to determine which app to route to?

Comment: Thank you. I feel like because it is in a k8s cluster that wont work but i could be wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using separate subdomains is better if your business can live with it. Your separate nginx containers in k8s is well suited for this solution.

It's complicated make one nginx & 2 SPA apps workin sub path, so it's better have 2 domains simply.

Comment: Is it safe to say in this case that the angular app has to know about this deployment scheme and logic must be included to handle it? I would prefer that the angular app doesnt care how it is deployed, it works the same regardless if it is being run locally or in the K8S cluster.

Comment: Angular app doesnt have to know about deployment scheme

Comment: Ok so with your suggested solution the angular code base does not have to know about the deployment scheme but if I were to use a path param to identify the app then it would have to know about the deployment scheme? The reason I ask is because you say that SPA has routing that relies on server. If it relies on server then wouldn't in this case logic have to be added to address the path param identification deployment scheme? Does that make sense?

Comment: SPA routing after website load does not rely on server, it routes internally in browser without reaching to server for route changes unless you refresh the tab. Sorry if my answer was making confusion on server dependency on SPA routing.

Comment: Routing in SPA is the same on local/kubernetes/docker when you use lcoalhost/a.example.com/b.example.com etc.

Comment: That last comment makes sense to me but you say in your comment ... "It's a bit tricky to have one nginx & 2 SPA apps in sub path because SPA has routing within its router rather than relying on server." ... This to me suggests that the SPA router or some part of the code base or server or something would have to changed. It would not be tricky if it just worked :)

Comment: Ah got it, I wanted to speak that sub pathing like example.com/app1 & example.com/app2 is complicated both in frontend and web server(nginx/apache etc).

Comment: Ok thanks it's complicated because stuff has to change or be maintained there? In the frontend and/or web server?

Comment: Yes exactly, both of frontend and backend need custom routing logic to make example.com/app1 & example.com/app2 solution work

Comment: Thank you @prosunshining ... answer accepted. To me it seems like having to manage stuff at server or application level to handle that kind of routing would make that the wrong way to do it.